# How to get Twitter User Website data from Twitter API for my Rails Devise sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth

I'm using Omniauth-Twitter with Device.

Twitter API gives me

```
{
  "id": 2244994945,
  "id_str": "2244994945",
  "name": "TwitterDev",
  "screen_name": "TwitterDev",
  "location": "Internet",
  "profile_location": null,
  "description": "Developer and Platform Relations @Twitter. We are developer advocates. We can't answer all your questions, but we listen to all of them!",
  "url": "http://twitter.com",
  "entities": {
    "url": {
      "urls": [
        {
          "url": "https://twitter.com",
          "expanded_url": "https://dev.twitter.com/",
          "display_url": "dev.twitter.com",
          "indices": [
            0,
            23
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "description": {
      "urls": []
    }
  },
.....
```

---

and I need to get the **expanded_url** for my website field, but it is in kinda array, how do I get that data?

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |designer|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid

      user.username = auth.info.nickname

      user.website = HERE_I_NEED_USERS_WEBISTE_INFO
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this to my designer.rb worked!

```
  begin 
    user.website = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(auth.info.urls.Website))['location']
    rescue
      user.website = auth.info.urls.Website
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have that twitter data in a variable called `twitter_data`. if it has the above structure, you'd be able to get to the `extended_url` this way:

```
twitter_data["entities"]["url"]["urls"].first["expanded_url"]
```

I'd recommend trying this in the console with some real data and seeing what you get.

Edit:

According to the `omniauth-twitter` gem doco, you can get all this info from the [authentication hash](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter#authentication-hash).

and it looks like you'd be able to get the relevant url like this:

```
auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
twitter_data = auth[:extra][:raw_info]
twitter_data["entities"]["url"]["urls"].first["expanded_url"]
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I add Twitter data to a variable as you suggested? Currently I pull data as auth.info.nickname

Comment: Ah good question. I read your question as you already had that data... what does the twitter API say about how to fetch that data?

Comment: the gem doco seems to have this: https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter#authentication-hash Might be useful stuff in the `auth[:extra][:raw_info]` section ?